# How to set sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail Template seperate for when group id 4 using module

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email-templates, customer-group

> How to send separate Email template
>   (customer_password_forgot_email_template) when
>
> user Group id=4 using
>   module **extend Mage_Customer_Model_Customer**.

```
class Creative_Login_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{
    public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {
        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

> This code working but i want separate mail template for only groupid=
>   4.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
     <Creative_Login>
         <version>0.0.1</version>
     </Creative_Login>
   </modules>
   <!-- After login hook -->
   <global>
      <models>
        <creative_login>
           <class>Creative_Login_Model</class>
        </creative_login>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <customer>Creative_Login_Model_Customer</customer>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
      </models>
      <template>
            <email>
                <customer_password_forgot_email_template translate="label" module="creative_login">
                    <label>Forgot Password</label>
                    <file>account_password_reset_confirmation_creative_login.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </customer_password_forgot_email_template>
            </email>
      </template>
   </global>
   <!-- ##################### -->

   <frontend>
       <!-- ########After login hook######### -->
      <events>
         <customer_login>
           <observers>
              <creative_customer_login>
                 <class>creative_login/observer</class>
                 <method>checkLoginStatus</method>             
              </creative_customer_login>
           </observers>
         </customer_login>
      </events>
       <!-- ##################### -->
       <!-- Before login hook -->
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <creative_login before="Mage_Customer">Creative_Login</creative_login>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
   </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ravi.As `you reweite customer class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`  and then  $t`his  give customer object`

in this function  you can get customer if by using below code :

```
  $this->getGroupId()
```

**also you need create an customer forgort pasword rest password email html template and define it config.xml**

**Step1:**  add new customer `forgot password confirmation mail template`  for `this customer group` using

```
below code at config.xml



<template>
        <email>
            <customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew translate="label" module="customer">
                <label>Forgot Password</label>
                <file>account_password_reset_confirmation_new.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew>
        </email>
    </template>
```

by this code i have add  **new email template** and **template code** is `customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew`

**Step2:** for getting this email template add below code  at outside  in config.xml

```
<default>
    <customer>
      <password>
                <forgot_email_template_newgroup>customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew</forgot_email_template_newgroup>
      </password>
    </customer>
</default>
```

**Step3:** you need to call this template `at  sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail` of rewrite function

```
if($this->getGroupId()==4) <!-- check your group id -->
     $this->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/password/forgot_email_template_newgroup', self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
      }
      else{
         $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
      }
```

**Step4:** `you to create new html name as account_password_reset_confirmation_new.html at app/locale/yourlanguage/template/email`

**Hope it will help you.**

Comment: Thanks, but how to set condition for only group 4 see my congif.xml at this all user same template access.

Comment: wait give you solution

Comment: hi W_Onestepcheckout how to override. 

class AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action