# Getting error while creating table in magento1.9 via setup script

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am trying to create an entity model along with creating table in setup script

but i am getting following error while running my setup script:
setup script giving error:Can't retrieve entity config account/account

Below is my model part of config.xml

Bank_Account_Model
                bank_account_resource

```
        <bank_account_resource>
            <class>Bank_Account_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <account>
                        <table>customer_account</table>
                </account>
            </entities>
        </bank_account_resource>
    </models>
```

Comment: put entire model configuration here. Mean while try to get your table like `getTable(bank_account/account)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

**How call a table in setup file using below code:**

If you have stay with your `code then try $this->getTable(bank_account/account)` .it should like `$this->getTable('yourmodeltype/entities')`

**Also.need check below thing:**

Check in config.xml

```
<models>
            <modelstype> <!-- need to change to bank_account to bankaccount>
                <class>Bank_Account_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>modelstype_resource</resourceModel>
            </modelstype>

    <modelstype_resource> <!-- need to change to bank_account to bankaccount>
            <class>Bank_Account_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <account>
                        <table>customer_account</table>
                </account>
            </entities>
        </modelstype_resource>
```

Also you need to set resource setup and add below code under `<global> tag`

```
<resources>
        <modelstype_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Bank_Account</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </modelstype_setup>
        <modelstype_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </modelstype_read>
        <modelstype_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </modelstype_write>
    </resources>
```

Comment: My entire module is working fine but it is not taking entity config i.e account/account the problem is only with when i try to call entity model table using $this->getTable('account/account');
It reads my setup script very well

Comment: if you have stay with your code then try $this->getTable(bank_account/account) .it should like $this->getTable('yourmodeltype/entities')

Comment: (y) cool that is what i am looking for Thanks amit bera :)

Comment: kia na bhai please check

Comment: what is mean by it?

Comment: bhai meaning dada(brother)

Comment: are u give me upvote? you need accept by correct sign.ex http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/how-to-set-sendpasswordresetconfirmationemail-template-seperate-for-when-group-i/36282#36282

Comment: Add your comment in main answer this will allow me to upvote "if you have stay with your code then try $this->getTable(bank_account/account) .it should like $this->getTable('yourmodeltype/entities') "
This is correct answer

Comment: check now.......

Comment: also needed to put config.xml code model and resource code on question . you give insufficient details

Comment: No no rest of the thing working fine only that comment given me my answer & i did upvote rest your wish weather you want to include it in your main answer or not ;)