# How to extend AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController and Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have default magento mage_customer extend but onestepcheckout on issue.

AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController also extend mage_checkout account controller.

so how to extend both account controller.

1. AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController
2. Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action

[my template override function is working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/how-to-set-sendpasswordresetconfirmationemail-template-seperate-for-when-group-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController` already extends `Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action`. Now you need to extend both these controllers. For this you just need to make sure your custom module is depending on `AW_Onestepcheckout` module, so that it will indirectly depend upon the `Mage_Checkout`. Then you need to include `AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController` before your custom controller. ie

### 1) Make your custom module depending on the two modules

File : `app\etc\modules\Namepace_Modulename.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namepace_Modulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <AW_Onestepcheckout />
                <Mage_Checkout />  
            </depends>
        </Namepace_Modulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

### 2) Overwrite External Extension controller

Now you need to overwrite route of `AW_Onestepcheckout` module, so that, magento will use our custom extension before that external extension.

File : `app\code\local\Namespace\Modulaname\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <aw_onestepcheckout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_modulename before="AW_Onestepcheckout">Namespace_Modulename</namespace_modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </aw_onestepcheckout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### 3) Extend the external external extension's controller with our own controller

Now create custom controller like this.

File :  `app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\controllers\CustomController.php`

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','AW_Onestepcheckout').DS.'AjaxController.php');

class Namespace_Modulename_CustomController extends AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController
{
   // some code
}
```

Since `AW_Onestepcheckout_AjaxController` already extends the controller `Mage_Checkout_Conrtroller_Action`, it will automatically get included, when you extend the external extension's controller

Comment: i have added code but not call function. required rewrite function or not?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you

Comment: @RajeevKTomy I am having the same problem but the module I want to extend is "gomage_checkout" which is extending Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action,, I followed your method but it didn't helped :(